Deduplicating IDs accros two columns
the goal is to depulicate the IDs in P1ID and P2ID.
I'm working on SQL Server 2019.

IDs in ID_GROUP are not shared accross groups, but IDs occur both in P1ID and P2ID within a group
ID is ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ID_GROUP, P1_RANK, P2_RANK
the first occurence of the ID should be used, the rest discarded, first according to column
the table DesiredOutcome displays the desired results


CREATE TABLE InitialResultSet (
    ID INT,
    ID_GROUP  VARCHAR(10),
    P1ID BIGINT,
    P2ID BIGINT,
    P1_RANK VARCHAR(10),
    P2_RANK VARCHAR(10)
);


INSERT INTO InitialResultSet (ID, ID_GROUP , P1ID, P2ID, P1_RANK , P2_RANK ) VALUES
(1, 'A', 1, 2, '0001', '0002'), 
(2, 'A', 2, 3, '0002', '0005'), 
(3, 'B', 4, 5, '0002', '0026'), 
(4, 'B', 6, 8, '0017', '0024'), 
(5, 'B', 6, 9, '0017', '0043'), 
(6, 'B', 6, 10, '0017', '0044'), 
(7, 'B', 8, 7, '0024', '0098'), 
(8, 'B', 9, 7, '0043', '0098'), 
(9, 'B', 10, 7, '0044', '0098');


CREATE TABLE DesiredOutcome (
    ID INT,
    ID_GROUP VARCHAR(10),
    P1ID BIGINT,
    P2ID BIGINT,
    P1_RANK VARCHAR(10),
    P2_RANK VARCHAR(10)
);

INSERT INTO DesiredOutcome (ID, ID_GROUP , P1ID, P2ID, P1_RANK, P2_RANK) VALUES
(1, 'A', 1, 2, '0001', '0002'),
(3, 'B', 4, 5, '0002', '0026'),
(4, 'B', 6, 8, '0017', '0024'),
(8, 'B', 9, 7, '0043', '0098');

InitialResultSet



ID
ID_GROUP
P1ID
P2ID
P1_RANK
P2_RANK




1
A
1
2
0001
0002


2
A
2
3
0002
0005


3
B
4
5
0002
0026


4
B
6
8
0017
0024


5
B
6
9
0017
0043


6
B
6
10
0017
0044


7
B
8
7
0024
0098


8
B
9
7
0043
0098


9
B
10
7
0044
0098



DesiredOutcome



ID
ID_GROUP
P1ID
P2ID
P1_RANK
P2_RANK




1
A
1
2
0001
0002


3
B
4
5
0002
0026


4
B
6
8
0017
0024


8
B
9
7
0043
0098



fiddle

So what is your question here? What about your attempt(s) isn't working? What is your attempt(s)?

In your desired outcome, for the row with PID2=7 you chose to keep the 2nd duplicate record (ID=8) instead of the 1st (ID=7). why?

Why is row with ID=2 excluded from your desired results?

@BartMcEndree
ID=7 is invalid because this would duplicate the 8 which is present as P1ID  in ID = 4.
ID = 2 is excluded because it would duplicate the 2 with P1ID = 2 which is present as P2ID in ID = 1
Sorry for the lack of attemps. I will try to post failed attemps later on.

Please include an example where a P1ID or P2ID is duplicated but in a separate ID_Group

this won't happen in this use case as ID_GROUP are Adresses and PIDs are Persons, thus a PID can't live in a different ID_GROUP. The scenario occurs when possible combinations of households for adresses are matched (the other criterias are excluded from the example)

Here's the way to do it recursively. This follows each ID_GROUP in order and determines which nodes are kept. It generates and uses a text string of ids to match for the ones that have already been retained:
with dataX as (
    select *,
        row_number() over (partition by ID_GROUP order by ID) as gn,
        cast(concat('|', P1ID, '|', P2ID, '|') as varchar(max)) as payload
    from InitialResultSet
), chain as (
    select ID, ID_GROUP, gn, payload as allocated, 'Y' as keep
    from dataX where gn = 1
    union all
    select d.ID, d.ID_GROUP, d.gn,
        concat(c.allocated,
            case when allocated not like concat('%|', P1ID, '|%')
                  and allocated not like concat('%|', P2ID, '|%') then payload end),
        case when allocated not like concat('%|', P1ID, '%')
              and allocated not like concat('%|', P2ID, '|%') then 'Y' else 'N' end
    from chain c inner join dataX d
        on d.ID_GROUP = c.ID_GROUP and d.gn = c.gn + 1
)
select * from InitialResultSet
where ID in (select ID from chain where keep = 'Y');

Based on OP's description of ID it would be possible to use that value instead of gn in order to follow the nodes in sequence. (You might possibly get a better plan by explicitly sorting on the same columns too.)
Using gn does have the advantage in terms of recursion depth though. This query will never need more iterations than the size of the largest ID_GROUP whereas using ID will only add a single row on each pass and will involve significantly longer strings and corresponding scans. As a side benefit, this would also work under a different scenario where id values can be repeated across different ID_GROUPS.

Using wildcards in the like pattern without delimiters may fail as the values increase to multiple digits, e.g. '%42%' will match '|109427|'. Adding delimiters to the pattern, e.g. '%|42|%' avoids the problem.

@HABO Yeah, those were supposed to be in there. I ended up having to retype the whole thing after whole thing got erased so I was rushing a bit.

I created a #TEMP table that included ID, P1ID, and P2ID. I then used a db_cursor to loop thru the InitialResultSet. For each record I added ID, P1ID, and P2ID within #TEMP if P1ID and P2ID were unique within #TEMP.
CREATE TABLE #TEMP (
    ID INT,
    P1ID INT,
    P2ID INT
);  

DECLARE @ID INT;
DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR
FOR SELECT ID FROM InitialResultSet 
ORDER BY ID  --Shawnt00
OPEN db_cursor
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @ID

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN  
  INSERT INTO #TEMP(ID,P1ID,P2ID) SELECT ID,P1ID,P2ID 
  FROM InitialResultSet
  WHERE ID=@ID  
    AND P1ID NOT IN (SELECT P1ID FROM #TEMP)
    AND P2ID NOT IN (SELECT P2ID FROM #TEMP)
    AND P2ID NOT IN (SELECT P1ID FROM #TEMP)
    AND P1ID NOT IN (SELECT P2ID FROM #TEMP)

    FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @ID 
END 

CLOSE db_cursor  
DEALLOCATE db_cursor;

SELECT i.* 
FROM InitialResultSet i
INNER JOIN #TEMP t ON t.ID=i.ID 

fiddle



ID
ID_GROUP
P1ID
P2ID
P1_RANK
P2_RANK




1
A
1
2
0001
0002


3
B
4
5
0002
0026


4
B
6
8
0017
0024


8
B
9
7
0043
0098




This version uses a join on #TEMP https://dbfiddle.uk/hGLTftGV

Probably good idea to avoid global cursors (or cursors altogether, it's probably possible to solve with recursive cte)

Here is my recursive version https://dbfiddle.uk/irVe687M

Recursive CTE using CHARINDEX
WITH recursiveCTE as
(
  SELECT i.ID, i.ID_GROUP, i.P1ID, i.P2ID,  i.P1_RANK , i.P2_RANK, 
  CAST( ',' + CAST(i.P1ID as VARCHAR(10)) + ',' + CAST(i.P2ID as VARCHAR(10)) as VARCHAR(512) ) + ',' as [idcsv], 
  2 as IDcount, 
  0 as exclude  
  FROM InitialResultSet i
  WHERE i.ID=1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT i.ID,  i.ID_GROUP, i.P1ID, i.P2ID,  i.P1_RANK , i.P2_RANK, 
  CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(',' + CAST(i.P1ID as VARCHAR(10)) + ',', idcsv) + CHARINDEX( ',' + CAST(i.P2ID as VARCHAR(10)) + ',', idcsv) > 0 THEN idcsv
  ELSE CAST([idcsv] + ',' + CAST(i.P1ID as VARCHAR(10)) + ',' + CAST(i.P2ID as VARCHAR(10))  as VARCHAR(512) ) + ',' END,
  IDcount + 1,
  CHARINDEX(',' + CAST(i.P1ID as VARCHAR(10)) + ',', idcsv) + CHARINDEX( ',' + CAST(i.P2ID as VARCHAR(10)) + ',', idcsv) as exclude
  FROM recursiveCTE r
  INNER JOIN InitialResultSet i on i.ID=r.IDcount
)
SELECT r.ID,  r.ID_GROUP, r.P1ID, r.P2ID, r.P1_RANK, r.P2_RANK 
FROM recursiveCTE r
WHERE exclude=0

fiddle



ID
ID_GROUP
P1ID
P2ID
P1_RANK
P2_RANK




1
A
1
2
0001
0002


3
B
4
5
0002
0026


4
B
6
8
0017
0024


8
B
9
7
0043
0098



